# Problemas con un Trigger (Disparador) en Google Script, solo en TEAM DRIVE

Tags: trigger, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive, google-forms

Tengo un proyecto que consta de hojas de calculo y formularios de Google, todo esto lo realicé en una carpeta de Mi Drive, esta es la situación dentro de un formulario tengo una pregunta con respuestas dinámicas y para que estas preguntas se cambien lo agregue en la secuencia de comandos de Google por medio de una función, a la función le asigne un disparador el cual se ejecuta al abrirse el formulario en modo editor, TODO funcionaba perfecto en mi drive, cuando hice una copia para moverlo al TEAM DRIVE de mi trabajo y asignarle un nuevo disparador este simplemente no funciona, me manda error pero no me dice especificamente que es. Alguien sabe si hay algún problema con que esté en el Team Drive de mi trabajo?

Ejecucion la cual yo reproducí por medio del editor:
[image: Ejecucion la cual yo reproducí por medio del editor]

Ejecución realizada por el Trigger:
[image: Ejecución realizada por el Trigger]

Esta es la funcion por si ayuda en algo:

```
function onOpen(e) {

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var resumen = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById("ID")).getSheetByName('RESUMEN');


  var audit = resumen.getRange('A1:Z200').getValues();
  var arr = new Array;
  var cont = 1 ;
  arr[0] = "NP (No producción)";
  for(var i = 0; i<200;i++)
  {
    try
    {
      if(audit[i][20] == 'Externa' && audit[i][23] == 'PEN')
      {    
        arr[cont] = audit[i][10]+" - "+ audit[i][11] +" - "+ audit[i][13]+" - "+ Utilities.formatDate(audit[i][6], "GMT", "dd/MMM/yyyy")+ " ("+(i+1)+")";
        cont ++;
      }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      break;
    }

  }

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var it = form.getItems();
  var aud = it[1];
  var tit = aud.getTitle();

  if(it[1].getTitle() == 'Detalles de auditoría')
  {
    var list = aud.asListItem();
    var tam= arr.length;

      if(tam > 0)
      {
        list.setChoiceValues(arr);
      }
      else
      {
        list.setChoiceValues(['']);

      }

    list.isRequired();



  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Cuando se crea una proyecto de secuencia de comandos en Mi Unidad este automáticamente tiene un proyecto de Cloud Platform asociado, pero esto no es hace en los proyectos creados  Team Drive. Los registros de error se almacenan en el proyecto de Cloud Platform, así que para ver el mensaje de error deberás vincular un proyecto de Cloud Platform.
2. DriveApp no siempre funciona con contenido en Unidades de Equipo, por lo que podría ser necesario que uses el servicio avanzado de Google Drive.

Notas al margen

1. Tienes dos  `var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();`. El segundo es innecesario.